# How do I eager load related data from a model NOT pulled from the db context in MVC (i.e. after model creation)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to load related data for a model AFTER the creation of it. For example, I know I can use eager loading in the following example:

```
Users user = dbcontext.Users.Where(x => x.userID == id).Include(x => x.Offices).FirstOrDefault();
```

That's all well and good, but what if I wanted to do something like this:

```
Users user = new Users();
user.FirstName = "John";
user.LastName = "Doe";
user.Phone = "123-45-6789";
user.OfficeId = 5;
```

This model doesn't exist in the database yet. How exactly can I send this to my view and get the office name contained within it by using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.Offices.OfficeName)
```

I see article after article explaining about eager loading, lazy loading, and explicit loading. But none of them seem to explain how I can eager load (or even lazy load) a model I have explicitly created. What can I do to send this data through?

Comment: Move `Offices` to it's own member in your view model, then just populate it separate from your `user`.

Comment: So are you suggesting something in the view like: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Offices.OfficeName).Where(x =>x.Offices.OfficeId == x.Users.OfficeId)? Is there no way to do it otherwise?

Comment: wait is `Offices` enumerable?

Comment: No, and I might have put the razor code there incorrectly too!  I can add Offices to my view model, I'm just not sure how I would reference it within my view model as I would want to in my original post.

Comment: @mxmissile, I ended up following your advice. From what I read, you cannot eager, lazy, or explicit load for an entity that has not been created in the database yet. I ended up taking your advice and creating Offices as it's own member. If you post your response as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Offices` to it's own member in your view model, then just populate it separate from your user.